# How to make in java an http post returning binary data using plain Sockets

Tags: java, http, sockets, binary

Because some restrictions, I have to use plain Java sockets to download a file published in a http web site. This is how i am reading the response:

```
String serverIp = "192....";
int serverPort = 3000;
String url = "/path/to/file";

Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

String postContent = "content";

writer.write("POST " + url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
writer.write("Content-length: " + postContent.length() + "\r\n");
writer.write("\r\n");
writer.write(postContent);
writer.flush();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
        //Process header
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

int intChar = -1;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while ((intChar = reader.read()) >= 0) {
    out.write(intChar);
}
byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();

File outFile = new File("myfile.zip");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
fileOutputStream.write(byteArray);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Every thing works fine, but the file `myfile.zip` is saved inconsistent. If I use unzip to uncompress the file, I get the error:

```
Archive:  myfile.zip
error [myfile.zip]:  missing 55053 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [myfile.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

When I use `curl` to do the http post, `myfile.zip` download consistent and I can open it.

Any light?

Comment: *"is saved inconsistent"* - is not a usable error description. Apart from that what you do is not proper HTTP: a POST request should have a body with a given Content-length. There should be no space after `HTTP/1.0` and before newline. The request should contain the path only and not the absolut URL. The hostname should be inside the `Host:` header. And since the data are binary you should not do character-based reading but instead byte-based reading.

Comment: I updated the code including the suggestions of 
Steffen Ullrich.  Still does't work

Comment: Which java version? As newer java versions have a facilitating HTTP client on board.

Comment: It's running with Java 1.8

Comment: BufferedReader, as the name implies, performs buffering. That means it tries to read ahead. As a result, the binary data that is past the HTTP headers also gets read into the BufferedReader's buffers. Perhaps creating a BufferedReader with a buffer size of 1 would be a successful hack.

Comment: Perhaps a better alternative is to use a DataInputStream. It also has a readLine() method, but is based on the InputStream interface and is properly byte oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.  I used the suggestion of
[President James K. Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/president-james-k-polk) to write the following solution:

```
String serverIp = "192....";
int serverPort = 3000;
String url = "/path/to/file";

Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

String postContent = "content";

writer.write("POST " + url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
writer.write("Content-length: " + postContent.length() + "\r\n");
writer.write("\r\n");
writer.write(postContent);
writer.flush();

DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int c = -1;
StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();

while ((c = reader.read()) >= 0) {
    header.append((char) c);
    if (header.length() > 4 && header.substring(header.length() - 4).equals("\r\n\r\n")) {
        break;
    }
}

File outFile = new File("myfile.zip");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
while ((c = reader.read()) >= 0) {
    fileOutputStream.write(c);
}

reader.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
```